# How to find workspace name?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

How do I find the workspace name from the message using Slack bot for Python? I can find username using the following:

```
username = message.channel._client.users[message.body['user']]['id']
```

But I don't know how to find the workspace name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was experimenting with the above solution and decided to explore the dictionary that was returned with:

```
username = message.channel._client.users[message.body['user']]
```

It is possible to obtain team id much easier with Slack bot like this (the solution was in plain sight all along):

```
username = message.channel._client.users[message.body['user']]['team_id']
```

But thank you for your assistance, @Erik! :)

Comment: Sadly, no! But the team_id is a good enough unique identifier for my purposes. :)

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to call [`auth.test`](https://api.slack.com/methods/auth.test) with the token of the respective team ID.

It will return the workspace name for the token / team ID in the `team` property.

Example output:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "url": "https://subarachnoid.slack.com/",
    "team": "Subarachnoid Workspace",
    "user": "grace",
    "team_id": "T12345678",
    "user_id": "W12345678"
}
```

Example code for Python 3.6+ / slackClient 2.1:

```
import slack

client = slack.WebClient(token='YOUR_TOKEN')
response = client.auth_test()
print(response['team'])
```

Example code for Python < 3.6 / slackClient v1

```
from slackclient import SlackClient

response = self.sc.api_call('auth.test')
if not response['ok']:
    raise RuntimeError("...")
else:
    print response['team']
```

Comment: Ho do I call the `auth.test` method and grab the `team` id?

Comment: It's a normal API method. I can add the python code for slackclient2

Comment: I found an easier solution below, but thank you for your help!